# How to use one module from another

Tags: f#, module

I have two F# modules, say a module called A in A.fs and B in B.fs. However, when I use module A from module B, F# does not see it. I've tried all combinations of `open` directives, i.e., `open A`, `open MyNamespace.A`, and so on - nothing helps. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do your two modules have the same namespace? If they do `open A` should be enough, if they are in the right order (as @PetPaulsen suggests).

Comment: possible duplicate of [F# defining and using a type/module in another file in the same project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172888/f-defining-and-using-a-type-module-in-another-file-in-the-same-project)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I am guessing.
The order the files appear in the project explorer is important.
When you want to use module A from module B, A.fs has to appear before B.fs.

Comment: Yes, you can move files with shift up/down if I recall correctly

Comment: On my machine it is ALT+up / ALT+down.

Comment: On my machine, the visual order did not map to the order the project system was supplying them to `fsc.exe` (which was clear from the invocation command line in the VS output [`Ctrl-Alt-O`] window). I edited/reordered the `.fsproj` and all was well (one cause may have been having `<Link>` and/or various `<None` or `<EmbeddedResource` elements but all adding of files was via the VS dialogs)

Comment: @SargeBorsch, I guess this is the best guess of F# history.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me after hours of searching.

Answer (score 5):

Since F# doesn't allow recursive modules (IIRC) the only thing you have to care about is that the order of modules is correct (you can't "forward declare" them) so that you build your adding a module that requires just the previous ones step by step.

If you ever find a situation in which you have a cyclic reference between a set of modules, then you will have to factor out the common part and remove the cycle.

This other question can clarify the topic: [F# mutual recursion between modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904889/f-mutual-recursion-between-modules)